# Generating Reply Email via MSGraph PHP SDK

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I am rebuilding an EWS-based system to use the Microsoft Graph REST API and I am having trouble replicating the **Reply Email** functionality as I had in the EWS implementation.

---

With EWS I would create a `ReplyToItemType`, specify the original email and attach the `NewBodyContent` like so:

```
$reply = new ReplyToItemType();

$reply->ReferenceItemId = new ItemIdType();
$reply->ReferenceItemId->Id = $this->message->ItemId->Id;
$reply->ReferenceItemId->ChangeKey = $this->message->ItemId->ChangeKey;

$reply->NewBodyContent = new BodyType();
$reply->NewBodyContent->BodyType = BodyTypeType::HTML;
$reply->NewBodyContent->_ = $this->body;
```

This would create a new message **with the content of the previous email already attached** and set the subject (i.e. `"RE: original subject"`)

---

With MSGraph, I don't seem to be able to replicate this functionality...

I am using the `POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/reply` endpoint (so specifies the message to reply to in the URL):

```
$this->graph = new Graph();
$this->graph->setAccessToken($token);

$graphRequest = $this->graph->createRequest(
    'POST', '/users/' . $mailbox . '/messages/' . $exchange_id . '/reply'
);

$graphRequest->attachBody($body)->execute();
```

The request body, `$body`, looks like:

```
array:1 [
  "Message" => array:6 [
    "sender" => array:1 [
      "emailAddress" => array:1 [
        "address" => "sender@domain.co.uk"
      ]
    ]
    "toRecipients" => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "emailAddress" => array:1 [
          "address" => "recipient@domain.co.uk"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "ccRecipients" => []
    "attachments" => []
    "body" => array:2 [
      "contentType" => "html"
      "content" => "<p>Test</p>"
    ]
    "subject" => "null"
  ]
]
```

But that sends an email with a subject "null" and with the content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way of replicating the EWS functionality as above, without having to attach the previous email content and subject manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing a message object, you're going to want to use the [comment property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) instead. Set it to a text string and it will become the top part of the reply message, with the quoted text from the original message appearing underneath as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks, this does work. I thought I had tried this previously but I must have structured the request incorrectly.